# Is there any way to run svn log on an entire repository (not just a checkout of trunk) without having to check it out?

Tags: svn, svndumpfilter

I've got a Subversion repository that our Atlassian Fisheye instances nearly chokes on because of some accidental commits + backouts ( i.e., someone tagged the entire repository instead of just /trunk, and on more than one occasion).
So what I want to do is audit the repo for larger-than-average commits, and carry out a dump+load to remove the bad commits using svndumpfilter.
I'm having a little trouble getting the size of each revision though. I'm nearly there. I've got the following which determines the size of each revision visible using svn log with a trunk checkout:

```
for r in `svn log -q | grep ^r | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr -d r`; 
do echo "revision $r is " `svn diff -c $r | wc -c` " bytes";
done
```

However, because the bad commits happened outside the trunk, running svn log on the working copy (of trunk) does not list them.
Instead I need the functionality of svn log to run repository wide. 
I COULD check-out the entire repository, but I don't have the days/weeks necessary to check-out all tags+branches.
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure, you can specify an URL to `svn log`:

```
svn log svn://server/repo
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, I also had to add the repo path after the "svn diff -c $r" buried in the command above, and it works perfectly.

Comment: If you are in a working copy of repository, "svn log ^/" is a compact version of the command.

Comment: can be also used with HTTP URL, `svn log https:://svn.server.com/path/to/repo`